# Usage and difference of KMC and IMK

Tags: security, hsm

What is the usage of Card Master Key and Issuer Master Key? What is the difference of these keys?

If I want to transfer one key to ICC, and also encrypt data using it by HSM, which type of key i should to use?

Answer (score 2):

**Issuer Master Key** is the bank's master key used to derive different CMKs for every card.

**Card Master Key** is key generated from IMK.
For emv cards, card master keys generated in Data Preperation phase and transfered to card during card personalization phase.

For security reason it is ok to use CMK to encrypt-decrypt card related tasks. If one key of cards is hacked other cards would be safe so IMK is safe.
There is different types of CMKs for different tasks . Which type of task key will be used for?

Comment: 1."Card Master Key is key generated from IMK": but in our HSM, we set Card Master Key manually. 2."Which type of task key will be used for": We want to encrypt some data by HSM, and then, decrypt it inside ICC using the key which transferred from HSM to ICC.

Comment: Which HSM you will use? It is easy in Eracom HSM because you have much control for keys but for Thales key usage is restricted to certain scenarios-commands.